# install grub 0.97 to new 4TB disk

Tags: grub, gpt

Stooped question but I cant understand why it not work.

I have rhel 5.5 kernel 2.18. I clone OS from 750 gb disk to another 4 TB disk.

I parted disk to 2 partition.

1. 10gb sda1
2. 40 gb sda2

I clone data from 750gb disk to 4tb by rsync.
`chroot` to 4tb disk and try to install grub.
I install grub to sda1 by two methods

1)  `grub-install /dev/sda1` - not work it say what cant see stage 1 and stage2.

```
grub/device map is ok ( consist hd0 sda )
```

2)  `echo -en 'root (hd0,0)\nsetup (hd0)'| grub --batch`. It grub batch mode. Install process end fine but after it not booted (I wrote about it in next).

I try maketable with gpt and with old fdisk (msdos table) 
I know what disk more 2TB make by parted with gpt.

When I parted by `gparted` then it do first part with `id = 0xee`. If I boot system then grub do error "unknown type of partition". If I in grub (by parttype) selected `id=0x83` grub say - "`unknown filesystem`". And more. After I booted with livecd gparted can see only one partition (only sda1 and cant see sda2) why ?

When I parted 4TB disk by fdisk and install by grub batch mode. Then I booting grub it ended with "error 5" after load stage 1.5

I solve my problem by `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` but it so stupid. 
Why I cant parted 4TB disk by `gparted` and it cant work? 
Direct me to right target.

Comment: RHEL 5 is past end of life and has limited support for 4TB disks. Upgrade to a currently supported Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition type `0xee` is a dummy entry in a MBR partition table, telling non-GPT-aware things that the disk is occupied by something they won't understand.

The version of GRUB in RHEL 5.5 will not understand GPT-style partitioning: it will only know about MBR.

If you need to support systems that are this old, the standard recommendation is to virtualize them if at all possible. Virtualization will normally give you tools to present disk space to the VM in ways that are not tied to the size of the actual physical disk(s). In this case, you could present the 4 TB disk as multiple virtual devices, each sized at 2 TB or less.

---

If you cannot virtualize this system, there is one dirty hack that might be possible. **Do not attempt this without making sure you'll understand the procedure and its effects.** If you upgrade your hardware to something that supports GPT at the firmware level, this setup is likely to stop working... but then you'll have new ways to solve your problem anyway.

First, make a GPT partition table with the partitions you want. The partition that contains your `/boot` directory (= usually, either your root filesystem or a dedicated `/boot` filesystem) should be fully within the first 2 TB of the disk. Make a note the exact start & end block numbers of this partition. Set the GPT partition type to regular "Linux filesystem" on each partition.

When creating a GPT partition table, `gparted` will have also created a "protective" fake MBR partition that has type `0xee` and covers the entire disk starting from block #1 and ends at the maximum possible value for MBR, at 2 TB.

The next step is to carefully edit the MBR partition table using `fdisk` so that it has one partition that has MBR partition type `0x83` and its start & end block values **exactly match** the first partition specified in the GPT partition table. You can even mark this MBR partition as active, so that the BIOS will assuredly detect the disk as bootable. The second partition entry should cover the rest of the disk (up to 2 TB) and have type `0xee`.

Now, you'll have a *hybrid* partitioning scheme, in which the first partition will be recognizable by both MBR and GPT partitioning schemes, but the second partition (the one that goes beyond 2 TB) will only be valid under a GPT partitioning scheme.

When installing GRUB 0.97 on such a disk, you must remember that you cannot embed GRUB stage1.5 into the area after the MBR and before the beginning of partitions, as this area is where the GPT partition table lives. You don't want to damage it. To make sure this does not happen, [you may need to use the `install` command in the GRUB shell to install the bootloader, rather than rely on automation provided by `grub-install` or the `setup` command of the GRUB shell.](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/install.html#install)

Now, when the system is booting, the BIOS should see a valid MBR with one valid, bootable partition (and one strange `0xee` thing it can ignore). The BIOS will read the MBR and execute the boot code in it, which will be the first stage of GRUB 0.97.

GRUB will now use the BIOS functions to load its second stage from a pre-recorded position within the first partition, then activate its own filesystem support (still using BIOS functions for low-level disk access) and read the `menu.lst` file, and the Linux kernel and initrd files from the specified "GRUB root partition", and start the Linux kernel. At that point, GRUB's job is done.

Now, the Linux kernel starts up and loads its own storage drivers from initrd. Unlike the BIOS, Linux can now address the full capacity of the disk and understand the GPT partition table (RHEL has had GPT support starting from RHEL 4). As a valid GPT partition table exists, the MBR is secondary and will be ignored. Linux will see and be able to use both partitions.

Comment: Thanks for rise answer. Its very difficult hack I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 2.18 is really old, but it should support GPT partitions. Using GRUB 0.97 to boot from a GPT partition should be no problem, but you need a file system the GRUB understands. If GRUB says `unknown filesystem`, then the filesystem is probably unknown to GRUB. You didn't mention which filesystem you use. Changing the filesystem does not change the type of the filesystem on disk, it is merely an indication what filesystem should be expected inside the partition.

A partition with 1GB at the start of the disk with EXT2 filesystem should be fine. Copy the files normally expected by GRUB to that partition, then run GRUB and execute these commands:

```
device (hd0) /dev/sda
root (hd0,0)
setup (hd0)
```

Your disk should now boot.

Comment: I cant write history. I only remember that I done. I also try ext2 and ext3 but it cant me help. May be I something forgotten.